# Return all roles contained in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to return all users with roles specified in a string array

I have tried the backward logic that one SO link shows but that narrowly misses what I am trying to get done

```
  string[] userRoles = { "2", "5", "6" };

  var users = UserManager.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => 
    y.RoleId).Contains("2").ToList();
```

This returns users with roleId 2 as obvious. What I am trying to return is all users in the role specified in the array

Comment: Feels strange to store Ids as `string` though

Comment: @Rafalon I know. But they have been defined somewhere else on the users table

Comment: @SeM I don't think so, at least based on the title. OP wants to get all users who have a specific role, not a user that has all the roles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand what you are asking, you would use `Where`, `Any`, `Contains`

```
string[] userRoles = { "2", "5", "6" };

var users = UserManager.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => userRoles.Contains(y.RoleId)))
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`UserManager.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Select(y => 
    y.RoleId).Contains("2").ToList();`

You can use

`UserManager.Users.Where(user => user.Roles.Any(r => userRoles.Any(ur=> ur == r.RoleId.ToString()))).ToList();`

Here you're saying you want all the users that have any of the role Ids existing in the userRoles table, I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks!! That helped